# Unexpected Response From Get Request Angular 2

Tags: angular

**Background**

Angular 2 app is working with a PHP API on my localhost. I know my URL end points are set up correctly because I checked them with Postman. When I make my get request the response is the html of my own page. I get a success code 200 but the response errors out because

**Error**

> EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

So when I console.log(res) I get this,

// My own HTML from the angular 2 front end.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head> etc...
```

I am expecting this in the response,

```
{
  "error": true,
  "api_key": false,
  "message": "User is registered in our database now use update api to fill other details"
}
```

**Question**

What would cause the response to hold my own html from the page I am making the initial request from?

**Code Example**

My get request

```
  public checkRegister(model: LogReg) {
      // Parameters obj-
      let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('email', model.email);
      params.set('email_verified', model.email_verified);
      //Http request-
      return this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_LOGIN,
          { search: params }).map((res:Response) =>  res.json());
      }
```

This is how I am handling the response,

```
 // Login Or Register User On Our Server
        this.logreg = new LogReg(profile.email_verified, profile.email);
        this.checkRegister(this.logreg).subscribe((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
            if (profile.email_verified === false) {
                console.log(res);
                console.log("Check your email to verify your account!");
                this.logout(this.user);
            }

            else if (res.profile_exist === false) {
                console.log(res);
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');

            } else if (res.profile_exist === true) {
                console.log(res);
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/overview');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

res.json is what is causing the error that you are seeing to answer your question.

res.json is attempting to parse the payload of the response which judging by your console to log is not json at all. you can wrap the res.json in a try catch in order to prevent the error from breaking your application from moving forward.

You might want to trigger the get request with the network tab open in dev tools and verify your request is sending what you are expecting. Also i suspect that you would want to send a post request if you are hitting an API call to check against a payload.

Comment: It is my php api. It is json. the response I am showing you is the HTML from the web page I am sending the get request from. Literally the response has the whole page in it. Not the response that the PHP is sending or what it shows when I check the api endpoint in Postman.

Comment: It is most likely failing to send to the correct end point. which is why i recommend you check you network traffic  to verify its going where expected. otherwise it might be hitting "/" which would then serve you page back to you.

Comment: I was able to check it in the node console. The URL is being built perfectly. it is the same URL I am using in Postman with the same parameters and yet the response is not the JSON response I would expect.

Comment: Postman is a service used to check api end points. I can send you screen shots of it if you like. Here I will update my question stand by

Comment: i use postman on a daily basis i understand that. in chrome if you press f12 it will open up the dev tools, there is a network tab there. trigger the get request while viewing that screen, you should see the get request show up in there. if you click on it, you can learn more about what is happening. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Bro, I know what the network tab is. What I am trying to say in the past 5 post is, yes brother. I have checked. It is a 200 response. Which I state in my question above. I am using postman, chrome dev tools (Clicking the "Network Tab") and the node console.

Comment: if all else fails hardcode the request string. without seeing the network request I can't tell you anything further.